# Calculate # of factorials between 1 and X

Tags: c++

I'm a bit stuck on getting started computing the number of factorials between 1 and n. An easy solution would be to just use a factorial table.

For example, between 1 and 362,880 there is 1!, 2!, 3! ... 8! and 9!. The program would then output that there are 8 factorials between 1! and 9!.

==

I am also working on a separate Boolean function that determines if a number X is a factorial. For example, if X is 5,040 it would return True but if it's 5,033 it would return False. This must use calculations, not list. Could someone point me in the right direction?

...

Definitely need recursion here, right?

Comment: Why can't you use a look up table?

Comment: Because we haven't covered that in class yet. :) I guess it'll need to use a loop and/or recursion.

Comment: Well, you need to calculate all of them anyway, so why not just keep calculating factorials until you hit (past) the limit.

Comment: Seems to me that if you find the largest factorial `<=` X you've found your answer - it would be order of that factorial.  And to find the largest wouldn't you just divide by 2, then 3, then 4, ...

Comment: @user2105644 but it's [so easy :(](http://ideone.com/DucGlA).

Comment: @Rapptz tell me about it!!! Driving me crazy, I guess the whole idea is to get people thinking...

Comment: You say that you're stuck, you describe the problem, but you give us no idea what you're stuck on. Where are you running into trouble?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am stuck getting started with the general idea, especially for the separate Boolean function. I don't know what Hot Licks means by just dividing by 2 then 3 then 4, ect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same algorithm for both : Considering the pseudo-code

```
i = 1
calc = 1
while calc < X
   i = i + 1
   calc = calc * i

 // is X a factorial number ?
if calc == X
   true
else
   false

 //How many between 1 and X ?
  i - 1
```

Comment: I think you have 2 problems with your pseudo-code: 1 i should be increased before calc uses it, 2 - according to his definition between 1 and X (i -1) not i

Comment: @Slava yes, when I run Tezirgs code it returns incorrect information. For example, it says there are 5 factorials between 1 and 50. However, I have made adjustments so that it seems to work :)

Answer (score 0):

If the range is largeish, perhaps using [Stirling's approximation](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_Formula) to get to nearest factorial (numerically solving n! = value) is a better idea.